# Notepad++ Extended Search Mode String

Tags: replace, null, notepad++

All I'm trying to do is search for a string made up of "s(NULL).(NULL)g", where (NULL) is an actual null character in Notepad++.

I figured out how to search for null as /0, but I don't know how to compose a string to search for 's''\0''.''\0''g'.

If you could help me out, I would really appreciate it.

Thanks! :)

Answer (score 1):

do a notepad++ regex search using the following:

```
s\x00\.\x00g
```